# Combinatorics with a condition.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, arithmetic-combinatorics

Jane is giving gifts to 3 sets of  cousins who are brother-sister pairs. 
She gives the gifts one after the other to her 6 cousins on the condition  that no brother receives a gift before his sister.

In how many ways can this be done?

I just need an approach for it as it is not of the type that I have done before.. ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets call the brothers and sisters $a,b,c,A,B,C$ respectively (where $a$ is brother to $A$, etc...)

Arrange the sisters in any order.  Suppose for illustration that it was order $A~B~C$.

Put the brother of the final sister appearing in line into the line somewhere behind his sister.  $A~B~C~c$

Put the brother of the second to last sister appearing in line into the line somewhere behind his sister (need not be adjacent).

> There are three allowable positions for $b$ pictured here $A~B~\underline{~}~C~\underline{~}~c~\underline{~}$

Put the remaining brother into the line somewhere behind his sister (need not be adjacent).

> Suppose for illustration that the result of the previous selection was $A~B~C~b~c$.  Then for this step, the available choices are pictured as $A~\underline{~}~B~\underline{~}~C~\underline{~}~b~\underline{~}~c~\underline{~}~$

Count how many choices are available for each step and verify that having made this sequence of choices creates a good arrangement exactly once as well as that every arrangement is achievable by such a sequence of choices.  Conclude using multiplication principle.

Comment: So I tried this : A B and C can be arranged in 3! Ways. Assuming this arrangement - A B C... Then c has only one place to go thereafter b has 3 choices and a has 12 choices  so Number  Of ways = 3!  * 12 = 78....!  Which seems wrong ; where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Sudhanshu How do you figure that a has 12 choices?  $3!$ for arranging the sisters is good, so is $1$ choices for the last brother, $3$ choices for the second to last brother,

Comment: Oh! It should  be 15 right...  sorry for the trouble...

Answer (score 5):

We use the notation of JMoravitz. Suppose the $6$ people are arranged at random, with all arrangements equally likely. Then there are $6!$ arrangements. We count the *favourables*, where each brother is (somewhere) to the right of his sister. The argument uses symmetry. It will be phrased probabilistically, but it can be reframed using counting.

The probability a is somewhere to the right of A is $\frac{1}{2}$. **Given** that a is to the right of A, the probability b is to the right of B is $\frac{1}{2}$. And given both of these have happened, the probability c is to the right of C is $\frac{1}{2}$. So the probability every brother is somewhere to the right of his sister is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$, and therefore the number of favourables is $\frac{6!}{2^3}$.

Comment: I didn't understand the emphasis on GIVEN shouldn't probability that b is to the right of B be 1/2 always.... and likewise for c...?

Comment: Indeed the probabilities are $1/2$ always. But in order to justify the multiplications formally, we need to work with conditional probabilities.  Alternately, we could argue that interchanging X and x gives a bijection between the arrangements with X to the left of x and the arrangements with x to the right of X, but that would take longer to say.

Comment: I enjoy seeing sufficiently different approaches in these sorts of problems.  It acts as a reminder that there isn't just one way of looking at things.  Indeed, if you were to go through and generalize this problem to $2n$ brother-sister pairs, my answer would read as $n!(2n-1)!!$ while yours reads $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$.  After some algebraic manipulation, they agree.  Which answer is preferred I suppose depends on which you learn to be comfortable with first.

Comment: Yes, it is good to have two proofs, or three, or more. Your approach is more direct, more hands on concrete, and therefore arguably more valuable.